# I have some issues deploying to heroku

Tags: node.js

im trying to deploy a project to heroku , everything appears to work just fine but when trying to accsess the url given

[this is what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8oEL.png)

can anyone have an idea what seems to be the problem?
i've tried looking for a solution via heroku.com but came up short.

if you need a screenshot of anything please tell me what is relevant cause i'm new at this.

here is the package.json for the backend

```
{
"name": "server",
"version": "1.0.0",
"engines": { "node": "14.x" },
"description": "production ready server",
"main": "server.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server:dev": "set NODE_ENV=development&&nodemon server.js",
    "server:prod": "set NODE_ENV=production&&node server.js"
},
"author": "Me",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "express-socket.io-session": "^1.3.5",
    "mongo": "^0.1.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.7.3",
    "socket.io": "^4.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "1.18.10"
}
```

}

Comment: Did you add a Procfile?

Comment: No, as far as I know it is no longer needed.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs